# A stagnation check for heuristics, especially simulated annealing?

Tags: heuristics, simulated-annealing

I'm studying heuristics for a course in my Master's. Our professor has told us that in order to point to a higher grade in the exam, we should check if our algorithm hits a stagnation points and that we have not seen any clear improvements to the optimum we have found. He asked it for some algorithms, especially the Simulated Annealing.
My idea was to store the best optimum found in the last n iteration into a queue and to check how it changes. He didn't like this approach. Is there any way to change my approach to make it useful at least for SA? Do you have any other stagnation check approach that can be used for my study case?

Thank you all in advance